# Need to input text into a POST website using python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to input text into the text boxon this website:

```
http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html
```

I then require the return page's html to be returned. 
I have looked at other solutions. But i am aware that there is no solution for all.
I have seen selenium, but im do not understand its documentation and how i can apply it.
 Please help me out thanks.

BTW i have some experience with beautifulsoup, if it helps.

Comment: Check out the _[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)_ library.

Comment: Im not sure how it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out the requests module. It is super easy to use to make any kind of HTTP request and gives you complete control of any extra headers or form completion payload data you would need to POST data to the website you want to.

P.S. If all else fails, make the request you want to make to the website in a web browser and get the curl address of the request using an inspector. Then you can just start a python script and exec the curl command (which you might need to install on your system if you dont have it) with the parameters in the curl request you copied